# Conditional && statement running when only one condition is met

Tags: java

Sorry I couldn't find something specific enough to answer my question, why is the statement that has the first condition true being ignored whilst the second which isn't being ran?

```
       [Code in debugger][1]
```

[image]

```
 } else if (batAOnStrike && batThreeOnStrike ) {
        batThreeScore += 1;
        batThreeBallsFaced += 1;
        batThreeStrikeRate = batThreeScore * 100 / batThreeBallsFaced;
        displayBatAScore(batThreeScore);
        displayBatABalls(batThreeBallsFaced);
        displayStrikeBatA(batThreeStrikeRate);
        teamScore += 1;
        scoreCalc();
        ranRuns += 1;
        batDecider();
    }  if (batBOnStrike && batThreeOnStrike ) {
        batThreeScore += 1;
        batThreeBallsFaced += 1;
        batThreeStrikeRate = batThreeScore * 100 / batThreeBallsFaced;
        displayBatBScore(batThreeScore);
        displayBatBBalls(batThreeBallsFaced);
        displayStrikeBatB(batThreeStrikeRate);
        teamScore += 1;
        scoreCalc();
        ranRuns += 1;
        batDecider();
```

Comment: Please consider editing and improving your question. Ask it as if we have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing or what your problem is, as if we can't read minds.

Comment: Was wondering why the bottom statement is running when only one of the conditions is met. Couldn't figure out how to show photo.

Comment: Your phrasing is unclear English. You have an "and" condition, and `batBOnStrike` is false. What is unexpected?

Comment: I think you may simply be confused as to how the debugger presents a breakpoint. It's waiting to evaluate the `if` condition. If you tell it to step it should jump over the block.

Comment: Think that is it, Thanks man

Comment: The code is **malformed**. The `if` statement is on the same line as the `}` ending the previous `else if`, so it *looks like* an `else if`, but it is not. It is a new statement that is entirely independent of the previous statement. Split the `}` and `if` on two lines to accurately reflect the code structure.

Answer (score -2):

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:

- `false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.
- `true || (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.

The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that the anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated, so any side effects of doing so do not take effect. Also note that the anything part of the above expression is any single logical expression (as indicated by the parentheses).

So if you **batAOnStrike** or **batBOnStrike** euqals to `false`, then there is no need to evaluate the **batThreeOnStrike**.